# How to use a column value as part of the file name created from a table using a unix ksh script

Tags: unix, ksh

I have a Unix ksh script that creates a file from a Snowflake table. I need to use the value in one of the columns in this table (same value for all rows) in the generated file name.

Instead of this...
filename=My_File_`date +%Y%m%d`.txt

I want this...
filename=My_File_**202120**.txt

...taken from the "Week_ID" column in this table:

| Col_A | Col_B | Week_ID | Col_D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| One | Two | 202120 | Dog |
| Three | Four | 202120 | Cat |
| Seven | Two | 202120 | Lizard |
| Two | Ten | 202120 | Bird |

Here is a mocked up version of my ksh script. What code and where do I add it to get the desired file name?

=================================

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh

set +x   

. /temp/users/omega/.tdlogon_prd2

TZ=":US/Pacific"

pipeFile=My_File_${WeekID}.pipe
filename=My_File_${WeekID}

rm -f ${pipeFile} ${filename}.txt

echo "COL_A|COL_B|WEEK_ID|COL_D" > ${filename}.txt


np_fexp <<EOF
 
.LOGTABLE ABC_DB.all_audiences_${Date};
 
.BEGIN EXPORT SESSIONS 10;


SELECT 

  ''||COALESCE(TRIM(COL_A),'')||'|'
    ||COALESCE(TRIM(COL_B),'')|| '|'
    ||COALESCE(TRIM(WEEK_ID),'')|| '|'
    ||COALESCE(TRIM(COL_D),'')
    
from  ABC_DB.my_table

;



.EXPORT OUTFILE ${pipeFile} 


MODE RECORD  
FORMAT TEXT; 
.END EXPORT; 

.LOGOFF;
.QUIT;
EOF
 
rc=$?

sed 's/\s\+$//g' ${pipeFile} >> ${filename}.txt


rm -f ${pipeFile}
```

=================================

I think I need to add something like this but I'm not sure if it is correct or where to add it in the above ksh script:

```
EXPORT REPORT FILE=${WeekID};
SELECT COALESCE(TRIM(WEEK_ID)) 
FROM ABC_DB.my_table
GROUP BY 1;
.IF ERRORCODE <> 0 THEN .QUIT 1;
.EXPORT RESET;

WeekID='${WeekID}'
```

Comment: Use separte steps.  First step is to assign a variable (e.g. week_id) from the database column.  Next step is to use that variable as part of the filename. How do you interface to the database? What is the RDBMS?  Just query `select min(week_id) from your_table` per your database interface...

Comment: Thanks, @mao. I updated the question with my full ksh script. I'm pretty sure that EXPORT OUTFILE and EXPORT REPORT FILE won't work together.

Comment: @mao / anyone else, any ideas?